# How to check if it's a string or json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json string that is converted from object by JSON.Stringify function.

I'd like to know if it's json string or just a regular string.

Is there any function like "isJson()" to check if it's json or not?

I'd like to use the function when I use local storage like the code below.

Thank you in advance!!

```
var Storage = function(){}

Storage.prototype = {

  setStorage: function(key, data){

    if(typeof data == 'object'){

      data = JSON.stringify(data);
      localStorage.setItem(key, data);     

    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(key, data);
    }

  },


  getStorage: function(key){

    var data = localStorage.getItem(key);

    if(isJson(data){ // is there any function to check if the argument is json or string?

      data = JSON.parse(data);
      return data;

    } else {

      return data;
    }

  }

}

var storage = new Storage();

storage.setStorage('test', {x:'x', y:'y'});

console.log(storage.getStorage('test'));
```

Comment: There is no method like this.  However `typeof` is the right and efficient way to handle this condition.

Comment: var isjson=false; try{JSON.parse(str);isjson=true;}catch(y){}

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The "easy" way is to `try` parsing and return the unparsed string on failure:

```
var data = localStorage[key];
try {return JSON.parse(data);}
catch(e) {return data;}
```

Comment: the above fails for number eg: JSON.parse(1)=1 but for string its good

Comment: depending on of exceptions for control of flow is not good practice.
https://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Answer (score 15):

you can easily make one using `JSON.parse`. When it receives a not valid JSON string it throws an exception.

```
function isJSON(data) {
   var ret = true;
   try {
      JSON.parse(data);
   }catch(e) {
      ret = false;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean down? Ok then.
EDIT: You got an upvote before you ask.

Answer (score 6):

Found this in another post [How do you know if an object is JSON in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481614/how-do-you-know-if-an-object-is-json-in-javascript)

```
function isJSON(data) {
    var isJson = false
    try {
        // this works with JSON string and JSON object, not sure about others
       var json = $.parseJSON(data);
       isJson = typeof json === 'object' ;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error('data is not JSON');
    }
    return isJson;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is "How to check if it's a string or json" maybe a simple way would be to check for string, so you would have done something like this somewhere:

```
    if (typeof data === 'string') { // check for string!
      //... do something
    } else {///... do something else}
```

Maybe that could be enough depending on your overall solution, just in case someone else is looking around.

Answer (score 1):

I think returning parsed JSON at the same time is a good idea, so I prefer following version:

```
function tryParse(str) {
    try {
        return { value: JSON.parse(str), isValid: true }
    } catch (e) {
        return { value: str, isValid: false }
    }
}
```

As you probably know `JSON.parse("1234")`, `JSON.parse("0")`, `JSON.parse("false")` and `JSON.parse("null")` won't raise Exception and will return true. all this values are valid JSON but if you want to see `isValid` is `true` only for objects (e.g: `{ "key": "value" }`) and arrays (e.g: `[{ "key": "value" }]`) you can use following version:

```
function tryParse(str) {
    try {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(str);
        return { value: parsed , isValid: typeof parsed === 'object'}
    } catch (e) {
        return { value: str, isValid: false }
    }
}
```

Comment: `1234`, `0`, `false` and `null`  are not valid JSON, those are Numbers, Boolean and Null, they are implicitly converted to String in [`JSON.parse`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.2) . Due to that implicit conversion those values result into these Strings `"1234"`, `"0"`, `"false"` and `"null"` which are then indeed valid JSON. It is that same as if you would have `var test = {toString() {return 1}}; console.log(JSON.parse(test))`, this can also be parse and results in `1` but that  would not make `test` to be valid JSON.

Comment: For that use cases you need more code, that can not be done with 4 lines of simple code, I think we talking about regular usage here not something like `{toString() {return 1}}`

Comment: My point is that for `JSON.parse(1234)` the `1234` is **not** JSON, but a Number. That Number is implicitly converted to String within the `JSON.parse` function, but that does not change the fact that `1234` is not JSON. And I added the  `{toString() {return 1}}` to make it more clear, because for `JSON.parse({toString() {return 1}})` the same thing happens internally as for `JSON.parse(1234)` both are implicitly converted to a String that is valid JSON, but both of them are not JSON at the time they are passed to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I edited my answer, you mean `"1234"` is valid JSON but `1234` is not?

Comment: Exactly. Now it is correct. If you have `var a = 1`  and var `var b = "1"` then `typeof a` is `number` and `typeof b` is `string`, both `a` and `b` can be passed to `JSON.parse` and it would result in `1`, but only `b`  is in this case JSON, because it is a string based representation of the number `1`.

Comment: You have to separate the concepts of [valid JSON](https://www.json.org/) - from the idea of JSON encoded string in Javascript. For example `"1234"` and `1234` are both valid JSON, while `undefined` is not. If JS was a more sane language it would throw an error if you passed anything other than a string to JSON.parse instead of the implicit casting shenanigans.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused!

Comment: If you have a file `test.json` and that contents is just `"1234"` then this file holds the string with the value `1234`, the equivalent JSON representation in JavaScript would be `"\"1234\""`, because `JSON.parse("\"1234\"")` returns the `string` with the value `1234`. If the content of the file is just `1234` then this json file holds a number, the JSON representation in JS is then `"1234"` because `JSON.parse("1234")` returns the number with the value `1234`.  And for `JSON.parse(1234)` JS does `JSON.parse(String(1234))`.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ says both of `1234` and `"1234"`, where I can validate JSON that says `1234` is not valid JSON?

Comment: It depends in which context you are, `jsonlint` validates the content of the JSON string, and not in the context of JS. So if the content of the JSON string is `1234`  then this is valid JSON (a number),  if the content of the JSON string is `"1234"` then this is also valid JSONB (a number) . But the `1234` in JSON has to be `"1234"` in JS because JSON has to be encoded as string, and the `"1234"` has to be `"\"1234\""`. `JSON.parse("\"1234\"")` => `string`,   `JSON.parse("1234")` => `number`. And  `JSON.parse(1234)` =>  `JSON.parse(String(1234))` => `number`.

Comment: So, my answer before the edit was true? (_somehow_) (I mean now is more clear, but I think based on comments, before the edit was correct too, am I right? if I'm wrong, I should say I didn't get why)

Comment: No it was not for `JSON.parse(1234)` the `1234` is a JavaScript primitive (a Number), and not JSON. It would be the same as if you would say that for `var a = {"foo":1, "bar": 2}` the `{"foo":1, "bar": 2}` is JSON. You can copy it to a JSON validator and it would validate, because its text representation is JSON, but in the context of JavaScript the `{"foo":1, "bar": 2}` is a JavaScript object and not JSON, because you cannot write `JSON.parse({"foo":1, "bar": 2})`. Only if you would write `var a = '{"foo":1, "bar": 2}'`, then the string `'{"foo":1, "bar": 2}'` holds JSON.

Comment: Nice example, now I understand your point, thank you!