# How do we make JavaScript think that a string is JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, angular

I have a function which only works if JSON object is passed to it. If I pass a string to it, with same format as JSON, it doesnt work. So I want to make that function think that the string passed to it is a JSON. The string is indeed in the JSON format.

I also tried the following. I inputted the string through Ajax , with "handle as" parameter as "JSON", and then when I passed the result to the function it works.

So I deduced the problem is not with the string. How do i convert this string to JSON? If i get same string through ajax request and then passing it to function works, whereas directly passing it doesnt work.

Screenshot of console log:
[image]

Advance Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976897/converting-a-string-to-json-object)

Comment: You parse string to json when pass string refere this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745406/how-to-check-if-its-a-string-or-json

Comment: `So I deduced the problem is not with the string` - you'd be wrong, because if the string is exactly what is shown as `json1` in the *image*, then that is NOT JSON at all - how about you post, as **text** the **exact** string you're having an issue with

Comment: @ Jaromanda...please find exact string.... {
 "hello": "world",
 "places": ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Australia"]
}

Comment: What's this function you're using? What does "doesn't work" *mean*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, so you can't really specify types of function arguments up front. If you want that, look into [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org/).

JSON is nothing but a String, not a standalone type in JavaScript. To convert a JavaScript object to the equivalent JSON string representation use:

```
const myJSON = JSON.stringify ({ a: 'b' })
```

To get a JavaScript object back from a JSON string use:

```
JSON.parse (myJSON)
```

When going over the network, libraries can automatically return serialized objects if you specify the type as JSON. You haven't pasted any code, so I'm guessing that you haven't specified `application/json` as the `Content-Type` in your network request. Since you've tagged your question `jQuery`, take a look at `[$.getJSON][2]`, this should do what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Use **[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

```
function isJson(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function isJson(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

str = '{"a":1, "b":2}';
console.log(isJson(str)); // true

str1 = '{["a":1, "b":2]}';
console.log(isJson(str1)); // false
```